# Is gradle stored in a nexus repo?

Tags: gradle, nexus

This is for downloading gradle itself. I'm trying to cache it inside a corporate network as easily as possible. If gradle is available in a nexus repo upstream, then I can point the distributionUrl for the wrapper to the internal nexus.

Maven is available in maven central which is convenient and I was trying to find a similar solution.
https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.apache.maven%20a:apache-maven

I did find but I was wondering if there was something more official.
https://github.com/hazendaz/gradle
https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.github.hazendaz.gradle%20a:gradle

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately no. The Gradle Wrapper JAR is not published to a Maven repository such as Nexus.

You can see on [this](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/fa4d3ad3ffd3ec3c321e5715879cecbb85a2aebd/subprojects/wrapper/src/main/java/org/gradle/wrapper/Install.java#L68) line where the actual download occurs. Digging further in you can see [here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/fa4d3ad3ffd3ec3c321e5715879cecbb85a2aebd/subprojects/wrapper/src/main/java/org/gradle/wrapper/Download.java#L80) Gradle uses lower level Java mechanisms to download the wrapper.

All Gradle distributions are available here: https://services.gradle.org/distributions/. If you look at the [version information](https://services.gradle.org/versions/), there is a JSON file that contains what the latest release version is. I'm not entirely familiar with managing Nexus, but if you could somehow create a plugin of some sort to poll that version information, then you could download it if it's not already available/cached in Nexus.

Answer (score 4):

When using Nexus you can create a `raw (proxy)` repository for `https://services.gradle.org/distributions`. This will proxy all requests.

In this instance the repository is named `gradle-distributions`. This allows you to use:

```
curl https://nexus.example-organisation.com/repository/gradle-distributions/gradle-6.9.1-wrapper.jar.sha256
e996d452d2645e70c01c11143ca2d3742734a28da2bf61f25c82bdc288c9e637
```

Instead of:

```
curl https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.9.1-wrapper.jar.sha256
e996d452d2645e70c01c11143ca2d3742734a28da2bf61f25c82bdc288c9e637
```

So then in `gradle-wrapper.properties` you can use:

```
distributionUrl=https://nexus.example-organisation.com/repository/gradle-distributions/gradle-6.9.1-bin.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution offered by M.P. Korstanje did not work for me directly, b/c my version of Nexus does not allow me to proxy raw websites. However, I was able to achieve similar functionality by creating a Hosted "Site" repository, and then uploading the Gradle bin zips to my repo with this script:

```
#/bin/bash

#
# This helper script will upload any file to 'Gradle Distributions' Nexus repo
#

NEXUS_ADMIN_USER=$1
GRADLE_BIN_ZIP_FILE=$2

if    [ -z "$NEXUS_ADMIN_USER" ] \
   || [ -z "$GRADLE_BIN_ZIP_FILE" ]
then
  echo "$0 <NEXUS_ADMIN_USER> <GRADLE_BIN_ZIP_FILE>"
  exit 1
fi

curl -v \
    --user $NEXUS_ADMIN_USER \
    --upload-file $GRADLE_BIN_ZIP_FILE \
    http://nexus-host:8081/nexus/content/sites/gradle-distributions/$GRADLE_BIN_ZIP_FILE
```

So now all of the approved Gradle distros are available at a Nexus-managed URL:

```
http://nexus-host:8081/nexus/content/sites/gradle-distributions/
  ├── gradle-3.5.1-bin.zip
  ├── gradle-7.4.1-bin.zip
  ├── gradle-7.4.2-bin.zip
  └── upload_gradle_distro.sh
```

The last step is to modify `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=http\://nexus-host\:8081/nexus/content/sites/gradle-distributions/gradle-7.4.2-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```